# Trying to make a fetch in a class

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component, Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"; 

const options = [
  { value: "red", label: "red" },
  { value: "blue", label: "blue" },
  { value: "green", label: "green" }
];

export default class CrearPost extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null
  };
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    /*I added all this*/ 
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");

    const PostData = () => {
      fetch('/createpost', { /*This route is in my nodejs server*/ 
        method:'post',
        headers:{
          'Content-Type':'application/json',
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt")
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
          title,
          body
        })
      }).then(res=>res.json())
      .then(data=>{
        console.log(data)
        if(data.error){
          alert(data.error)
        }
        else{
          alert('Post created')
          history.push('/')
        }
      }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div align="center">
      <Fragment>
        <Select
          className="basic-single"
          classNamePrefix="select"
          defaultValue={options[0]}
          isDisabled={false}
          isLoading={false}
          isClearable={true}
          isRtl={false}
          isSearchable={true}
          name="color"
          options={options}
          value={title}/*I added this*/ 
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}/*I added this*/ 
        />
      </Fragment>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="body"
        value={body}/*I added this*/ 
        onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}/*I added this*/ 
      />
      <button onClick={() => PostData()}/*I added this*/>
        Submit post
      </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to make fetch but I get an error,
In `PostData` array function but I am getting the error maybe in that part.
Even I tried to make the `fetch` as is it were a function, but this doesn't work.
And in buttons I call `PostData` function because is there where I have the fetch
the error is the next:

[image: Error picture]

Comment: Can I help you changing your class component into functional component ? Because you mixed up function component features with class based components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change:

```
 const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");
```

into this

```
state = {
    selectedOption: null,
    title: "",
    body: ""
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up  functional component with classify component. [`react hooks`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) use in functional component, which is [`stateless`](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/stateful-stateless-components-react/). class component is a [`stateful`](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/stateful-stateless-components-react/) component and has its own `state`. So you don't need to `useState` in class component. Just try out change your state to:

```
this.state = {
    title: "",
    body: ""
  };
```

For understanding difference between functional and classify component, see this link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functional-components-vs-class-components-in-react/